# Raspberry pi not getting ip from cable modem?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, ethernet

Cable internet with netgear cg3700 modem, the router part is disabled so it strictly works as a modem and i can use up to 4 ip adresses at the same time.

Windows based machines goes online just fine through ethernet, cell phone and surf pad goes online just fine through wifi.

Raspberry pi3b goes online just fine through wifi but fails miserably with ethernet.

ip 169.254.164.42
netmask 255.255.0.0
broadcast 169.254.255.255

What is wrong and how do i correct it?
Regards

Comment: Is  169.254.164.42  some kind of zeroconf IP address?  Assigned by Avahi?

Comment: Pi relevance?  The use of the Pi doesn't mean the question is Pi related.

Comment: Very difficult to answer. What subnet (ips) is on ethernet and on wifi? Is there a DHCP server? Is there a NAT that translates the Link-local addresses to public addresses? Link-local addresses are not routed in the internet. Is there a ppoe? Is there a router anywhere?

Comment: what is a "surf pad"?

Comment: are you sure that dhcp is functioning correctly on the router?